# How to initialize a bean from a static method with a parameter that is defined in another class in spring

Tags: spring, parameters, factory

I want to create a new DateTimeFormatter as a bean, and hand it to another bean.

This is how I'd do it in code...

`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("blah");`

But how do I initialize formatter in Spring?

Here's the solution I came up with inspired by the helpful responses

```
<bean id="dateFormatter" class="org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat" factory-method="forPattern">
  <constructor-arg value="blah"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've used Spring, but here goes:

`DateTimeFormatter` does not extend from an interface (I only found reference to the Joda one), hence anything that uses it has to reference the type exactly.  This means you are not going to get any benefit from dependency injection (because what uses the formatter is tightly coupled to the exact type of the formatter).  So do you really want to do this?

Assuming you do, [from the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-ctor), look at sections 4.3.2.2 and on, and it gives you all the ways to create a bean.  You can create the formatter via a static method, and then pass it into the constructor of what uses it (Constructor injection, section 4.4.1.1)